# Why java takes overhead of thread switching when OS is acting on behalf

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, operating-system, pthreads

Okay I learned that java consults OS for thread creation, i mean java uses OS API to create threads for multiprocessor CPU. So if OS is managing threads on behalf of JAVA then why java takes other overhead of thread management like storing thread frames and thread locals on stack and other thread related activities. Why can't OS alone takes care of it and let java not to care about anything related to threads.

Comment: Because Java is designed to run on any kind of platform, even on one that doesn't provide native threads. In all cases, JVM need to have some kind of internal structure to manage support for thread (it's in in its design) native or not.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What else would you use a thread stack for if not pushing stack frames and local variables onto it during method calls?

Comment: @the8472: actually that's what my question is. Why would i own thread stack if OS is managing threading on my behalf. When java has 1:1 mapping of its threads with OS, then why to keep thread related stuff both in JAVA's virtual thread stack and also in OS native thread stack.

Comment: @shyampatil You are right, there is no good reason to do this, which is why it doesn't. A thread has two stacks; one is virtual and one is real (the native stack). The virtual one only exists notionally.

Answer (score 1):

> then why to keep thread related stuff both in JAVA's virtual thread stack and also in OS native thread stack.

The abstract virtual machine described by the java language specification does involve a stack, yes. But that does not mean that real implementations use a stack that is separate from the native thread stack.

I.e. there is nothing that says an implementation has to use a native stack and some separate managed stacks.

Answer (score 0):

> why java takes other overhead of thread management like storing thread frames and thread locals on stack and other thread related activities. Why can't OS alone takes care of it and let java not to care about anything related to threads.

There is a bunch of information that Java needs to store about threads that is OS independent.  The thread name, daemon status, current lock monitors, etc..  It certainly offloads the actual scheduling and running of the thread to the OS but it needs to do a lot of administration of the threads to make sure that they work in concert with the JVM.

If you are talking more specifically of stack storage, then, as @the8472 states, most likely the JVM is making use of the native thread stack and doesn't create its own stack frames, etc..